# Using combineLatestWith with multiple stream values?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

RxJS `combineLatest` is deprecated and replaced with `combineLatestWith`.

How do we use it when we have 3 or more streams to combine?

I've developed this example for what I thought would work.

```
const hello$: Observable<string> = of('hello').pipe(
  combineLatestWith(of('world')),
  combineLatestWith(of('!')),
  map((arr) => {
    const greeting = arr[0];
    const subject = arr[1];
    const punctuation = arr[2];
    return greeting + ' - ' + subject + punctuation;
  })
);
```

[And this is the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cmna8r?file=index.ts)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combineLatestWith` joins the observable with the given one in an array (say cons). Imagine it like so:

1. `"hello"` => `"world"` = `["hello", "world"]`
2. `["hello", "world"]` => `"!"` = `[["hello", "world"], "!"]`

so arr becomes `[["hello", "world"], "!"]`
where `=>` is `combineLatestWith`

```
const hello$: Observable<string> = of('hello').pipe(
  combineLatestWith(of('world')),
  combineLatestWith(of('!')),
  map((arr) => {
    const first = arr[0];
    const greeting = first[0]
    const subject = first[1];
    const punctuation = arr[1];
    return greeting + ' - ' + subject + punctuation;
  })
);
```

From docs: `Create an observable that combines the latest values from all passed observables and the source into arrays and emits them.`

The code can look nicer with destructuring, like so:

```
const hello$: Observable<string> = of('hello').pipe(
  combineLatestWith(of('world')),
  combineLatestWith(of('!')),
  map((arr) => {
    const [[greeting, subject], punctuation] = arr;
    return greeting + ' - ' + subject + punctuation;
  })
);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9dbwfe?file=index.ts)

Comment: You can even do this

`
const hello$: Observable<string> = of('hello').pipe(
  combineLatestWith(of('world'), of('!')),
  map((arr) => {
    const [greeting, subject, punctuation] = arr;
    return greeting + ' - ' + subject + punctuation;
  })
);
`

Comment: @Pankaj, I find your approach much easier to grasp than to `combineWithLatest` each source separately  and mapping / flattening the results afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the observables at hand you might also want to consider `combineLatest` which will combine the latest emitted values of each observable into an array. The number of elements in that array is equal to the number of observables you put in `combineLatest`:

```js
const a$ = from(['a']);
const b$ = from(['b']);
const c$ = from(['c']);

const x$ =
  combineLatest([a$, b$, c$])
    .pipe(map(([a, b, c]) => `${a}.${b}.${c}`));
    
x$.subscribe(str => console.log(str));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.5.7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
const {from, combineLatest} = rxjs;
const {map} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```

Comment: I was also doing that, however `combineLatest` was deprecated in RxJS 6.  https://medium.com/volosoft/whats-new-in-rxjs-7-a11cc564c6c0#:~:text=The%20combineLatest%20operator%20was%20deprecated,replaced%20by%20the%20combineLatestWith%20operator.

Comment: @Ole AFAIK only the [operator version](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatest) was. The [high-level one](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) isn't.

Comment: OH!  Great to know!  I was getting deprecation warnings in Angular, but perhaps they pushed a release that deprecated a non operator declaration by mistake.  I was like man I thought `combineLatest` was working just fine :) ... Also really great answer.  You illustrated it very well.